# why http 307 internal redirect workig only on Chrome and not firefox?

Tags: security, firefox, https, http-headers, hsts

So I have an API endpoint to which CORS requests sent over `http` are redirected with the http `308 permanent redirect` in the response. In Firefox, the response is as expected, a `308` status code with the upgraded `https` location header to which Firefox outright rejects and refuse to redirect/upgrade to `https`. In Chrome however, the response from the API with the header `Non-Authoritative-Reason: HSTS` is set, to which Chrome performs `307 an internal redirect`. I understand why Chrome(cause of HSTS) does this, but how is this behavior isn't implemented in Firefox. In Firefox, the browser just rejects the CORS response despite the `308` redirect URL, while Chrome fakes a request and then upgrades automatically to the `https` version of the URL.

Comment: Looks like 307 – and as you noticed, 308 as well – are incorrectly implemented in Firefox. I doubt it will get any significant attention from the development team, though, seeing as a previous bug related to redirects (among them, 307) took them more than 3 years to fix.

Comment: @interDist Thanks for responding, I have actually tested the issue again in both browsers now, Chrome still continues with the same behavior while Firefox now although redirects correctly to the upgraded version of `https`, now it doesn't even show any `307` or `308` requests in the Network tab. I assume it was a bug and got fixed in the latest versions, although I'm still wondering why didn't they log the redirects in the Network tab.